# How to inspect code relating to specific content like villagers?

Tags: minecraft-modding, minecraft-bedrock-modding

I’m trying to make an add-on for Minecraft Bedrock edition.

I am following tutorials. How do I see the code of certain stuff so that I know how to edit it? Some of the stuff I'm going to be making requires me to understand how the code of certain things work so I can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the vanilla behavior and resource packs [here](https://github.com/ZtechNetwork/MCBVanillaBehaviorPack/releases). The villager code is in the `behavior_pack/entities/villager_v2.json` file.

Comment: To View their dialogs go to behavior_pack/trading and the dialogs should be there